# String starts with a certain string

Tags: c++, xcode, string, boolean

I have to write a program in which i ask the user multiple questions and if their answer starts with y consider it a true statement.

how can I write the string starts with statement

```
bool yes (string a)
 {
    string ans;
    string begin = "y";
    // compare the string to see if it starts with y
  if(string begins with y)
    return true;
  else 
    return false
 }
```

how can I do make that part I keep breaking my head trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest test would be to check if the string has a non-zero length, then look at the first character if it does:

```
bool is_yes(std::string const & str)
{
    return !str.empty() && (str[0] == 'y' || str[0] == 'Y');
}
```

(Note that I take a reference-to-constant-string as a parameter instead of just a string.  If the function accepts a string instead of a reference, the value of the string you pass to the function will be copied for no good reason.)

Answer (score 0):

in C++

```
#include <string> 
{
           string a="hello"
           if(a.front()=='Y')
           return true;
           else
           return false
}
```

Comment: If the string has zero length, the result of `std::string::front()` is undefined.